# How to convert tf.string to python string in TF 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

As the question says, how do I convert a `tf.string` tensor to a python `str`.
In TF 1.0 I can simply do

```py
sess.run(string_tensor)
```

But how do I do that in TF 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's the answer if anyone else has the same issue:

```py
string_tensor.numpy().decode("utf-8")
```